# how to get the triangles to draw a parabolic surface in 3D according the equation？

Tags: wpf, 3d, direct3d

I have the equation y= x^2 + z^2, how to get the triangles to draw the parabolic surface? 
and I want to use WPF 3D to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generate a 2D grid on the XZ plane, ranging between [-D,-D] and [+D,+D]
(D can be anything, like 10). You can write a nested loop to generate the triangles for this, I presume.

Now, while generating each vertex V `<x,z>`, simply generate V' `<x,x^2+z^2,z>` instead.

Comment: thanks Rahul. I think using parametric equation is better. y=u^2; x=ucos(t);z=usin(t);